# Why do many concrete blocks have this strange shape on either end?

Tags: concrete-block

[image]

I want to build a simple wall out of concrete blocks and notice some have this strange shape, the ends look like a capital letter "I". As best as I can tell from any picture, this isn't like LEGO, making them snap together.

Why is the shape like that? Is there some advantage to me as a consumer, building a wall, to buy this shape? For instance, will that provide greater strength to the wall?

Comment: if you google "concrete block shapes" you will find out that these are stretcher blocks. You can then google where stretcher blocks are used.

Comment: Look at it from a different angle: You've got 3 "I-beams" forming each block, the one in the center has a slightly longer top & bottom to allow it to connect to the ones at the end. Nothing at all strange about it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with most building materials, there is a balance between strength, weight, cost and other attributes.

Solid concrete blocks would weigh roughly twice as much as these blocks and cost twice as much too. But they wouldn't add that much strength. In addition, the hollow sections make it easy to grip, move and place the blocks, whether by man or machine.

With the blocks stacked in a wall so that the hollow areas are vertical or horizontal, the visible faces of the wall are solid. With the hollow areas vertical, they can be filled with concrete and rebar for additional strength, particularly including anchoring to a foundation: rebar embedded in the slab poking up into where the blocks are placed and then filled with concrete. [Here is one example article explaining how to do this](https://decentralizedinc.com/upgraded-cement-block-walls/).

As far as the "I" shape, that little gap in the middle of each end allows for mortar to hold the blocks together while still having the faces of the wall "just blocks".

Comment: Of the many block that I have laid, that recess on the ends are very handy for holding onto without jamming my fingers against the other block. If they were all shaped like corner or window block, the ergonomics of handling are a bit different, awkward, actually for me. But I have only laid hundreds of block over the past decades, not thousands as a pro might have and gotten past the awkwardness,